# Parallel items in Jenkins Declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am working on setting up automated build and deploy jobs in jenkins

Right now I have a single stage with parallel tasks set up like this

```
stage ('Testing & documenting'){
        steps {
            parallel (
                "PHPLOC" : {
                    echo "Running phploc"
                    sh "./src/vendor/phploc/phploc/phploc --exclude=./src/vendor --no-interaction --quiet --log-csv=./build/logs/loc.csv src tests"
                },
                "SLOC": {
                    echo "Running sloc"
                    sh "sloccount --duplicates --wide --details . > ./build/logs/sloccount.sc  2>/dev/null"
                },
                "CPD" : {
                    echo "Running copy-paste detection"
                    sh "./src/vendor/sebastian/phpcpd/phpcpd --fuzzy . --exclude src/vendor --log-pmd ./build/logs/phpcpd.xml || true"
                },
                "MD" : {
                    echo "Running mess detection on code"
                    sh "./src/vendor/phpmd/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd src xml phpmd_ruleset.xml --reportfile ./build/logs/phpmd_code.xml --exclude vendor,build --ignore-violations-on-exit --suffixes php"
                },
                "PHPUNIT" : {
                    echo "Running PHPUnit w/o code coverage"
                    sh "./src/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration phpunit-quick.xml" 
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

after reading https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/ I noticed that they use a different structure.

```
stage("Documenting and Testing") {
        parallel {
            stage("Documenting") {
                agent any
                stages {
                    stage("CPD") {
                        steps {
                            //CPD
                        }
                    }
                    stage("PMD") {
                        steps {
                            //PMD stuff
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("Testing") {
                agent any
                stages {
                    stage("PHPUnit") {
                        steps {
                            //PHPUnit
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am not sure what the difference between these two approaches is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example running `parallel` inside the `steps` block was introduced by the earlier versions of the declarative pipeline. This had some shortcomings. For example, to run each `parallel` branch on a different agent, you need to use a `node` step, and if you do that, the output of the `parallel` branch won’t be available for `post` directives (at a stage or pipeline level). Basically the old `parallel` step required you to use Scripted Pipeline within a Declarative Pipeline.

The second example is a true declarative syntax introduced to overcome the shortcomings of the former. In addition, this particular example runs two serial stages within the parallel stage ‘Documenting’.

You can read this official blog to know more about the `parallel` directive https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/.